# How to have nested form in reactive forms in Angular2+

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angular

I have two class as below

```
export interface Demo {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
    Parent: DemoParent;
}

export interface DemoParent {
    Id: number;
    Title: string;
}
```

Since the relation between `demo` and `parent` is `1-0..1` I want to edit it in same form.

My form is defined like below (for simplicity I removed all other fields and validators)

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      Name: [''],

    });
```

Now how should I add `parent` to my form, I googled and most of the articles are about nested array.

I don't want to flatten my object I want to keep the hierarchy

### Update

I tried below and still issue,

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      Name: [''],
      Parent: {
        Title: ['']
      }
    });

<input type="text" formControlName="Parent.Title"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody else has the same issue

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      Name: [''],
      Parent: this.fb.group({
        Title: ['']
      })
    });

<div class="row">
  <form [formGroup]="form">

    <input type="text" formControlName="Name"/>

    <div formGroupName="Parent">
      <input type="text" formControlName="Title"/>
    <div>

   </form>
</div>
```